# Eclipse 2023-12 IDE keeps freezing the UI for a couple of seconds, especially when editing javascript files

Tags: eclipse

I've upgraded a couple of weeks ago to the latest Eclipse for EE Developers, available for Linux:

Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0)
Build id: 20231201-2043

Ever since I've did this upgrade, whenever I am editing javascript files, the IDE console keeps freezing for ~5 seconds, for no apparent reasons, just to end up presenting an empty  suggestion box.

Any idea how I can disable this behavior? It is extremely annoying.

Thanks

PS: I've already disabled all the JS related checkboxes under General-> Editors -> Text Editors ->Hyperlinking but no change.

Eclipse is running on a Fedora 39 system

java -version
java version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 21.0.1+12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-jvmci-23.1-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 21.0.1+12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-jvmci-23.1-b19, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Is it any different with yesterday's release of 2024-03?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in the current Eclipse version 2024-03? If yes, can you reproduce it when you open the JavaScript file in a plain text editor? If no, which JavaScript editor do you use (if you open JavaScript files in the Generic Text Editor, it's Eclipse Wild Web Developer) of which version?